# Icon font are rendered as squares on subsequent visits in Safari (iOS and OSX)

Tags: safari, mobile-safari, webfonts, icon-fonts

We're experiencing a weird problem with font icons. First couple of visit they load beautifully, but after a period of idle (usually around 24 hours) on subsequent visits they are replaced by squares. In Chrome, Firefox and even IE it works without problems.

When the problem is there I can see the CSS with the embedded font in the inspector but the font does not render. The CSS is cached and it feels like the font is evicted from the cache but never loaded again.

We have tried different ways of hosting, bootstrapcdn, our own CDN, and now fonticons.com. No real change. The really weird part is that the problem only arises after some time.

Anyone with a similar problem?

Site is [www.mentimeter.com](https://www.mentimeter.com).

Comment: In my case i just change css link to `<link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">`. Now it's working, why? No idea... :)

Comment: Using the CDN worked for me as well. I only had the problem rendering 1 specific icon.

Comment: I had a similar issue, I posted a solution here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29696700/font-awesome-icon-not-displaying-in-safari-and-ipad