# Font awesome - Safari (8.0) not display icons

Tags: javascript, html, css, font-awesome

Instead of font icons i got this squares instead of arrows.

It happens when app is on server. On localhost is working. Why?

[image]

Just standard url:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css" type="text/css">
```

and code:

```
<i id="car-select-right" class="fa fa-caret-right"></i>
```

When i refresh site, its start working.

Comment: How we know from just image?

Comment: Please provide the relevant extract of your code, without it we can only guess. Without any code my best guesses would be that you either haven't uploaded the font files or you haven't set up the necessary MIME types on your server.

Comment: Look in your console

Comment: Nothing special in console.

Comment: We got a similar problem, nothing in console. Fonts are just gone. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30193615/icon-font-are-rendered-as-squares-on-subsequent-visits-in-safari-ios-and-osx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed css link to `<link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">`. Now it's working.

Comment: Are you sure? We've moved around to different CDNs but the problem always resurfaces, unfortunately..