# Font awesome icons not visible on Macbook Pro (Macbook Pro users welcome)

Tags: html, css, macos

OK, here is the thing. A client of mine claims he cannot see the social icons (on the left side of the screen) when viewing the website on Macbook Pro with Safari. Those icons are perfectly visible on all devices I've tested it with. Is there any Macbook Pro users that can confirm the bug? I'd really appreciate it. The website URL is as follows:

http://goo.gl/2hdIra

I really think it's the client's issue, but he keeps pushing me.

Comment: I think this might be too narrow? Also, do you really need all those tags? And if this has nothing to do with programming (it might though) [apple.se] is the right place.

Comment: It works good for me. Safari 9.0.3 @ MBP 13" Retina. Maybe client resized window and media query hide icons?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29696700/font-awesome-icon-not-displaying-in-safari-and-ipad?answertab=votes#tab-top

Comment: @crashet Thanks, mate. That's what I thought initially, but he claims he didn't do this. Anyways, really appreciate your response!

Comment: Turned out that the issue was the Adblocker!

Answer (score 3):

I checked it out in Chrome, Firefox, and Safari on a Macbook Pro. Works fine.

Just a heads up, I had this happen on a site I was working on recently - the Ad Blocker was responsible.

I think some blockers are sensitive, and interpret social icons as popups.

Comment: Trevor, you are the third to confirm. Thank you very much!